# Sharepoint 2010 Search Service results inconsistency

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 (full SP, not foundation services) that I am retrieving results from. However, depending on the page number I specify, the number of results available changes.

For example, I might ask my query to get Page number 4 and 20 records, and the result set says there is about 7000 records total available. I then change the page to 200, it now says I have only 2500 available.

Here's an example of the XML for the query I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query" Revision="1000">
<Query domain="QDomain">
 <SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format></SupportedFormats>
 <Context>
  <QueryText language="en-US" type="STRING" >test text  SCOPE:"All Sites"</QueryText>
 </Context>
<Properties><Property name="Filename" /><Property name="Rank" /><Property name="Title" /><Property name="Author" /><Property name="Size" /><Property name="Path" /><Property name="Description" /><Property name="Write" /><Property name="HitHighlightedSummary" /><Property name="HitHighlightedProperties" /></Properties><SortByProperties><SortByProperty name="Rank" direction="Descending" order="1"/></SortByProperties>
 <Range><StartAt>1</StartAt><Count>20</Count></Range>
 <EnableStemming>false</EnableStemming>
 <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>
 <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>
 <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior>
 <IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults>
 <IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults>
 <IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>
</Query></QueryPacket>
```

Is there a query tag or parameter I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats by design. The number of results are "estimated" and recalculated every time you switch pages. No query tag or parameter is missing. Welcome to SharePoint-Wonderland.

Here is a link. It is about SharePoint 2007 but applies to 2010 as well:
http://blogs.officezealot.com/mauro/archive/2009/03/07/21441.aspx

Comment: Thanks, makes sense then why the default Search results page doesn't have First/Last buttons, only page numbers and Next/Previous.